# Java JOGL - Changing Vertex Buffer

Tags: java, opengl, buffer, jogl

In my program the Vertex Buffer is initially gotten from a list of points. Essentially I would like to change the data in the buffer when I change data in my list.

I know how I would get my program to know when to try to update the buffer, but I do not know how I would go about changing the vertex buffer entirely or being able to change certain parts of it.

Notes:

- The list of points will never grow or shrink, just change the values, so the buffer would not have to change size if there is a way to update it with out entirely replacing it.
- Efficiency is not a concern :)

Comment: Use `glBufferSubData (...)` to update a single block of memory in a vertex buffer. If you need to alter several unconnected parts of the buffer you should use `glMapBuffer (...)` and `glUnmapBuffer (...)`, I am not sure how well Java handles memory mapping though... it probably will not be as efficient as a more traditional language like C.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I ended up using `glBufferSubData` for each individual update (max num updates ~100) and since there is an update about at most every 5 seconds it is not to big of a deal since this is a fairly simple project for a class.
Anyways, I just calculated where each vertex was in the buffer and modified it accordingly.